# ConcurrentModificationException trying to copy a working map

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, concurrentmodification

I am working with a long running task that has a thread that should check and print the status of the objects in the worker thread, I have the following

In the worker thread `HashMap<A,B> someStuff` is being actively read / written to, in my status thread I have

```
Map<A, B> someStuffCopy;
synchronized ( someStuff )
{
    someStuffCopy = new HashMap<A, B>( someStuff );
}
```

This works for a few cycles before I always encounter a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the line in the *synchronized* block.

I may be completely wrong in my approach, but I would like the be able to take a copy of the working set, apply some intermediate transformations, and then print out statistics.

What would fix the Exception?

Comment: Matt, What are the types `A` and `B`? Also, are you iterating over `someStuff`elsewhere? Also, does `someStuff` need to change after it is initially populated?

Comment: A and B are unimportant, and as stated, _someStuff_ is actively being read / written to, no other iterations. _ConcurentHashMap_ solved this.

Comment: `synchronized` only helps if *all* code accessing a resource will use it. It doesn’t protect against arbitrary access, it only excludes code synchronizing on the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code to diagnose the problem, but it is likely that using a threadsafe Map implementation may fix it:

```
someStuff = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Map<A, B> someStuffCopy;
synchronized ( someStuff ) {
    someStuffCopy = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, B>( someStuff );
}
```

Depending on what you're doing elsewhere, it could be that using `ConcurrentHashMap` for just the parameter `someStuff` is enough.

Comment: 1m+ iterations in and no exceptions, looks like that'll do it. Thank you kind sir. Cheers.

Comment: Try to remove the sychronized block, too.

Comment: the `someStuffCopy` does not need to be a `ConcurrentHashMap` instance either, as it is only being read from and never modified.